# Multiple bibliographies - one for each group of subfiles

Tags: bibtex, natbib, subfiles

I'm writing my thesis, and to allow working on separate sections more easily, I have broken the document down into subfiles. I have multiple subfiles per chapter, but I want to have one bibliography at the end of each chapter. I have seen solutions online that can put a bibliography after each individual subfile, but that isn't what I want.

This is my MWE:

main.txt

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}  
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}

\subfile{ch1/ch1_p1}
\subfile{ch1/ch1_p2}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{ch1}

\subfile{ch2/ch2_p1}
\bibliography{ch2}
\end{document}
```

subfiles:

```
%ch1/ch1_p1.tex
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\section{Chapter 1 section 1}
I like to cite \cite{A}
\end{document}

%ch1/ch1_p2.tex
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\section{Chapter 1 section 2}
But now I'd like to cite \cite{B}
\end{document}

%ch2/ch2_p1.tex
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\section{Chapter 2 section 1}
Now I cite \cite{G} which is something very different.
\end{document}
```

and my bibfiles:

```
%ch1.bib
@book{A,
    title={The meaning of A},
    author={A. Alpha},
    year=2019,
    publisher={Apublisher}
}
@book{B,
    title={The meaning of B},
    author={B. Beta},
    year=2019,
    publisher={Bpublisher}
}
%ch2.bib
@book{G,
    title={The meaning of G},
    author={G. Gamma},
    year=2019,
    publisher={Gpublisher}
}
```

At the moment the second bibliography doesn't print, it just reproduces the first one:[image: The output of my code]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think your problems result from a wrong use of `chapterbib`. Read its documentation, or checkout web resources. There are also other packages like `bibunits` and `multibib` that may help. I suggest to set up your document first without `subfiles`, and to introduce it only if you need it.

Comment: I definitely do need subfiles, or rather I now have over a hundred pages of thesis written using subfiles. I will read the chapterbib documentation in more detail. Thanks